# Append Parameter to the End of an Executable Download

Tags: javascript, php, html, download, exe

I was asked to append a parameter at the end of an executable file when it's downloaded and I don't even know where to start.

"Just append the /verysilent parameter after the download url – such as:
`http://www.yourdownloadurl.com /verysilent`.  Please note the space before the “/”."

Comment: Do you mean when you execute a program on the server from php?

Comment: um, it doesn't work like that. I mean you could add that to the link to the file, but then the download likely wouldn't work. But from what it sounds, they are trying to append a parameter so when the file runs on the user's computer it includes that parameter. You can't force a parameter on program run like that or else download the file `download.com/rm -rf *`

Comment: that's not going to work `/` is a path separator in urls. it's not an argument like it would be for a command line executable.

Comment: Appreciate your help and I forwarded your response to the lady who asked me to do this and she instructed me to use a "Command Line Parameter" and forwarded the following info.

Comment: /SILENT, /VERYSILENT
Instructs Setup to be silent or very silent. When Setup is silent the wizard and the background window are not displayed but the installation progress window is. When a setup is very silent this installation progress window is not displayed. Everything else is normal so for example error messages during installation are displayed and the startup prompt is (if you haven't disabled it with DisableStartupPrompt or the '/SP-' command line option explained above).

Comment: Does that help figure out what she wants me to do?